# Primitve Boxing StackManipulation

Tags: byte-buddy

There seems to be a difference in the implementation of PrimitiveBoxingDelegate and PrimitiveUnboxingDelegate.

Basically I would like to box a primitive value on the stack, so it can be returned as a reference (ie. the method returns Object)

PrimitiveUnboxingDelegate.forPrimitive() provides me with a StackManipulation but unfortunately PrimitiveBoxingDelegate.forPrimitive() does not.

Is there an easy way to create a boxing StackManipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, you just need to specify the type to which the value should be boxed to what is implicit for unboxing:

```
StackManipulation sm = PrimitiveBoxingDelegate
  .forPrimitive(...)
  .assignBoxedTo(..., Assigner.DEFAULT, Assigner.Typing.STATIC);
```

You can cast an `int` to for example a `Object` or a `Number`. You can however create illegal combinations as well what is sometimes necessary for Byte Buddy's own purposes.